# Abrir varios JFrame en Java

Tags: java, java-swing

estoy nuevo en programacion, y estoy abriendun JFrame principal, cuando quiero abrir desde el principal un jFrame secundario este lo abre fuera. Como hago para que los JFrame secundarios queden delimitados por el JFrame secundarios

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Lo que usted necesita es un [JInternalFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html).